# XPages - updating a Java Class design element

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm using a Java class design element in an XPages application and am having trouble making changes in this class. I've changed the signature of a Java method to take just two parameters instead of three but the XPage expects the old signature and gives an error saying that the method has not been found. I have set "xsp.application.forcefullrefresh=true" in the XSP properties but it has not helped. I've also tried restarting the http task and even restarting the server but I still have this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks very much for your fast response. That has indeed solved the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean the project at menu item `Project / Clean...` in designer.